# How to serialize a Julia function to a file using the Serialization package?

Tags: julia

How can I serialize a Julia function object to the disk so it can be later loaded by a different process without sharing the actual source file of that function.
Serialization seems to work with lambdas but seems to fail with functions.

```
using StatsBase, Serialization
flam = (x) -> mean(x) + 1
serialize("flam.ser", flam)
```

Now I open new Julia session and can deserialize the lambda function:

```
julia> using StatsBase, Serialization

julia> flam = deserialize("flam.ser")
#1 (generic function with 1 method)

julia> flam(5:7)
7.0
```

This approach will not work with a function though:

```
julia> f(x) = mean(x) + 1
f (generic function with 1 method)

julia> serialize("f.ser", f)
```

Now I try in a new Julia session:

```
julia> deserialize("f.ser")
ERROR: UndefVarError: #f not defined
```

How can I serialize the Julia function?

Answer (score 4):

If you want for some reason to store serialized functions, you need to serialize methods of a function rather the function itslef.
Following the previous code and adding an empty function without methods you could find out that actually no methods got serialized:

```
julia> function f end
f (generic function with 0 methods)

julia> deserialize("f.ser")
f (generic function with 0 methods)
```

Hence, we need to serialize methods of a function rather than the function itself:

```
julia> f(x) = 2*mean(x)
f (generic function with 1 method)

julia> f(x,y) = 4*mean(x) + y
f (generic function with 2 methods)

julia> serialize("f_first_method.ser", methods(f)[1])

julia> serialize("f_all_methods.ser", methods(f))
```

Now let us start a new Julia session:

```
julia> function f end
f (generic function with 0 methods)

julia> deserialize("f_first_method.ser")
f(x) in Main at REPL[6]:1

julia> f(6:7)
13.0

julia> deserialize("f_all_methods.ser")
# 2 methods for generic function "f":
[1] f(x) in Main at REPL[6]:1
[2] f(x, y) in Main at REPL[7]:1

julia> methods(f)
# 2 methods for generic function "f":
[1] f(x) in Main at REPL[6]:1
[2] f(x, y) in Main at REPL[7]:1

julia> f(6:7, 0)
26.0
```

Note that we needed to create an empty function `f` before starting deserialization of its methods.